# Javascript equivalent to LinqPad

Tags: javascript, linqpad, web-maker

I'd like a small javascript scratchpad in which I can write and test (non-DOM related) functions.

I'm not happy using the Firebug console to do this.

Does such a thing exist as a standalone app?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net or http://jsbin.com? (not standalone, but meh, that's why it's a comment).

Comment: Yep, well aware of both of these. Just wondering if there exists a desktop equivalent.

Comment: Press Shift + F4 in Firefox to start Scratchpad. It is better than console in firebug.

Comment: @AurA nice. didn't know about that.

Comment: Consider node.js REPL, or whichever is your favorite editor + some live coding plugin, ie. execute-post-save-and-show-me-the-output

Comment: It's unbelievable: *All* of these tools require you to do manual html to get any output. It's like I had to do xaml to get to see something with LinqPad. Is there really no simple tool in which I can type `"Hello"`, `"Hello".Dump()` and see the result!?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I was looking for the same thing.

Comment: @AurA   Firefox Scratchpad deprecated, use web console edit mode instead . check following url -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Deprecated_tools#Scratchpad

Comment: chrome devtools has snippet - check following url - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's [jQueryBuddy](http://jquerybuddy.codeplex.com/), currently in beta.

It does support DOM manipulation, but you don't have to use that if you don't need it. And like LinqPad it has a very similar Dump() method for viewing objects.

Comment: I have the same question as above. This tool looks like what I'm looking for, but unfortunately it seems to be abandonware at this point (last release seems to have been in 2010) - do you know if there's an alternate tool that does the same thing?

Comment: I took jquerybuddy a long time ago, and did a bunch of stuff to it to make it work the way I needed it to.  It doesn't have the Dump stuff anymore though.  My goal is to be able to edit snippets of html for angular components so it's got alot of changes based on that.  You could allways though just do like JSON.stringify() and output that in an html <pre> tag https://github.com/NathanielACollier/WebPad

Comment: There is also a chrome extension [tag:web-maker] see https://github.com/chinchang/web-maker